# Can program return from main? Why link register has same value as that of program counter?

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers, rtos

**UPDATE:**
Prototype of DNMManager_GetName function, asked by Codo.

### Screenshot 4

```
char* DNMManager_GetName(DNM_s* element)
{    //program stops here.
     //link register  : 0x805afed0
     //program counter: 0x805cda64

    return &element->Name[0];
}


          DNMManager_GetName():
805cda64:   E24DD008            sub        sp, sp, #8
805cda68:   E58D0000            str        r0, [sp]
```

---

I'm studying RTOS behavior that based on arm cortex-a8 CPU, by using breakpoint provided by IDE debugger.

In screenshot 1, I noticed that when program is frozen at entry point of `main` function, the link register contains 0x805dcda0, which is the address of `while(1)`.

`while(1)` *is NOT* the caller for `main` function, but link register contains address of `while(1)`.

Why?

And who put it?

### Screenshot 1

```
int main(void)
{                     //program stops at here. link register: 0x805dcda0

    OS_ERR  err = OS_ERR_NONE;

    IntAINTCInit();   //once program enters this function,
                      //the value of link register is changed
    OS_Init();        //initialize OS
    OSStart(&err);    //start OS

    if (err != OS_ERR_NONE)
    {
        printf("OS fails");
    }
    /*no return statement*/
}


          start_boot():
805dcd94:   E92D4008            push       {r3, lr}
138           CopyVectorTable();
805dcd98:   EB000001            bl         CopyVectorTable
141           main();
805dcd9c:   EB00001D            bl         main
143           while(1);
          $C$L1:
805dcda0:   EAFFFFFE            b          $C$L1
```

Screenshot 2 below is an example that shows value of link register is changed to correct value, the address of `OS_Init()` in this case, after program enters function IntAINTCInit().

### Screenshot 2

```
void IntAINTCInit(void)
{   //program stops here. link register: 0x805dce28

    /*pseudo code*/
    !!Reset the ARM interrupt controller
    !!Wait for the reset to complete 
    !!Enable any interrupt generation by setting priority threshold
    !!Register the default handler for all interrupts
}

44          OS_Init();      //initialize OS
805dce28:   EBFF30EA            bl         CPU_Init
```

---

Second question.

During program execution, I found that the value of program counter equals to the value of link register at some points of time.

It makes me confused in that I thought these both registers were never going to be the same value.

Screenshot 3 below is the case of two register's value being the same.

How does it happen? In what situation?

### Screenshot 3

```
DNM_s* p = DNMManager_Retrive(index);
if(NULL != p)
{
    char name_unicode[40] = {0};
    char name_utf8[40] = {0};
    memcpy(&name_unicode[0], DNMManager_GetName(p), 40);    //program stops here.
                                                            //link register  : 0x805afec8
                                                            //program counter: 0x805afec8
    enc_unicode_to_utf8(name_unicode, 20, name_utf8);
    memcpy(&((UI_DNM_RealList_s*)structs)->Name[0], &name_utf8[0], 40);              
}


366                     char name_utf8[40] = {0};
805afeb8:   E3A01000            mov        r1, #0
805afebc:   E28D004C            add        r0, sp, #0x40
805afec0:   E3A02028            mov        r2, #0x28
805afec4:   EB00D1FD            bl         memset
367                     memcpy(&name_unicode[0], DNMManager_GetName(p), 40);
805afec8:   E59D0020            ldr        r0, [sp, #0x14]
805afecc    EB0076E4            bl         DNMManager_GetName
805afed0:   E28DC024            add        r12, sp, #0x18
805afed4:   E1A01000            mov        r1, r0
805afed8:   E3A02028            mov        r2, #0x28
805afedc:   E1A0000C            mov        r0, r12
805afee0:   EB00C2EF            bl         memcpy
```

Comment: Please post this as text, not pictures. Surely you can export the disassembly as text logs.

Comment: What is your question? Doesn't the software work as expected? If so, describe what you expect and what happens instead. Or do you want to better understand how the ARM microcontroller works? Or what kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: What does `DNMManager_GetName` look like? Is it `volatile char* DNMManager_GetName(DNM_s volatile* element) { ... uint8_t temp[40] = {0}; ... return temp; }`? If so, a pointer to memory allocated on the stack is returned. The memory is deallocated the moment it returns. So this would be undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin Hi, the reason I post as picture is for clarity. Is text really better understanding than picture?

Comment: @Codo Yes. The software work as expected, But I think LR should store 0x805AFEE4(return address) rather than 0x805AFED0.

Comment: @Codo Yes, I want to better understand how ARM microcontroller works.

Comment: @Codo Hi. Your last comment is very informative for me. The last image shows prototype of `DNMManager_GetName`

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence **If so, a pointer to memory allocated on the stack is returned. The memory is deallocated the moment it returns. So this would be undefined behavior.** May you please explain more about it?

Comment: See [Return of Stack Variable Address](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/562.html) as an example. You must no return an address of a variable allocated on the stack. When you return from the function, the address becomes invalid as the stack will be reused by another function. The data the address is pointing to will be overwritten sooner or later. Therefore, it's undefined behavior and creates hard to find bugs. Use a linter. They can catch most of these bugs.

Comment: @Codo I now know what did you mean. The pointer is pointing to a global variable, not local, so there is no such problem.

Comment: I've tried my best for improving this post. For the picture issue, I cannot replace it with text because of consistency on question and answer.

Comment: This question is still totally unintelligible without zooming in on the screenshots.  (And useless to visually impaired readers who depend on screen readers.)  Include some code blocks containing the essential parts instead of or as well as your screenshots, like people told you to in comments when you first posted this.  https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode.  There's also not enough text explaining what you're asking, just a (correct) explanation of what PC and LR are.  They're equal after a `bx lr` or other return instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hi, thanks for your suggestion and I've adapted it.

Comment: Yup, that's *much* better.  Thanks for taking the time to make Stack Overflow better :)  I changed my downvote to an upvote, since the first question (about `main` returning to an infinite loop) is an interesting question I hadn't thought about.  I normally look at hosted code (under an OS), where `main` normally does return to code that calls `exit()`, not freestanding

Comment: @PeterCordes You are welcome. Although I'm not good at English, making this web better as hard as I can is of course my responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

As you only show a few screenshots and not the full code, I can only speculate...

**Screenshot 1: Entry Point**

Other than on Windows or Linux, the program of a microcontroller should not return from *main()*. There is nowhere to go. To protect against further damage, *LR* points to an endless loop. That's where the program flow would go if you accidentially return from *main()*.

**Screenshot 2: IntAINTCInit()**

No questions.

**Screenshot 3: PC = LR**

*LR* contains the return address when a function is entered. If the function calls additional functions, it must save *LR* (usually on the stack) and assign it a new value. The screenshot shows the state after the statement:

```
char name_utf8[40] = {0};
```

If you look at the assembly code, you can see that *memset* was called to initialize the 40 bytes to 0. So indeed another function was called and the screenshot shows the state right after returning from *memset*. And everytime a function has just returned, *PC* must equal *LR* because that's how a return works. So everything is ok here.

**Screenshot 4: DNMManager_GetName**

The screenshot shows the state right when entering *DNMManager_GetName()*. The call to this function was made by the statement:

```
805AFECC    bl  DNMManager_GetName
```

The statement after the call (where it needs to return to) is 0x805AFED0, exacytly what *LR* contains on the screenshot.

Note that the single line in the C code results in two function calls, one to *DNMManager_GetName()* and one to *memcpy*. 0x805AFEE4 will be the return address of the second function call. But screenshot 4 shows the state of the first function call.

Comment: Hi. I want to improve the quality of this post. However, I'm not sure editing the context is valid since it may result in mismatch between question and answer. Can you give me some suggestion?

Comment: It's no problem to improve questions and answer as long as the main message stays the same. But as you mention, it's usually  a bad idea to change to evolve them such that the main story changes. You're better off asking a new question. This question and answer doesn't seem to be very popular. So you're unlikely to attract many people anyway.

Comment: The purpose that I want to improve this post is for me to avoid being blocked from asking any more, however, I don't know where to get started , so I decided to improve question and answer.